# MongoDB query for deleted documents

Tags: mongodb

I will be running a nightly cron job to query a collection and then send results to another system.

I need to sync this collection between two systems.

Documents can be `remove`d from the host and this deletion needs to be reflected on the client system.

So - my question is, is there a way to query for documents that have been recently deleted?

I'm looking for something like `db.Collection.find({RECORDS_THAT_WERE_DELETED_YESTERDAY});`

I was reading about parsing the oplog. However, I don't have one setup yet. Is that something you can introduce into an existing DB?

Comment: maybe add a `deleted` field in your document and soft delete it, and store another field `deletedAt` to track when it was soft deleted

Comment: You can do this with change streams. In general any solution involving oplog parsing should be replaced with change streams.